# I'm trying to form an array member using another member of same class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, member

There is more to my code but where I'm stuck is that while I run this code it says INVALID USE OF NON STATIC MEMBER 'a'. Is this way invalid or is there something wrong with my code?

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class equation{
    public :
    int a;
    int arr[a][2];
    void seta(int r){
        a = r;
    }
    void setcoef(equation c){
        for(int i = 0; i<c.a; i++){
            cin>>arr[i][1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there is. In C++ array sizes have to be **constants**, they cannot be variables. To write this kind of code in C++ you should use either `std::vector` (best) or use dynamic allocation (i.e. `new`)

Comment: This is interesting; shouldn't the error be "Fields must have a constant size", then? What's with "Invalid use of non-static member"?

Comment: @RyanJonZhang it complains that `a` is used incorrectly. If `a` was meant to be `const static`, the declaration would be valid, compiler doesn't know human's intent.

Comment: @RyanJonZhang Well in this case there is a second problem, which is that the OP is trying to use a non-static field in the declaration of another field, which is also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that in standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant** but since `a` is a non-static data member  it requires an object to be used on. In other words we need `this` which is available not at compile time but at runtime and hence we get the mentioned error saying:

```
INVALID USE OF NON STATIC MEMBER 'a'.
```

To **solve** this you can make `a` a `constexpr static` data member as shown below. This works because using a static data member doesn't require a class object(and hence `this` pointer).

```
struct equation
{
    constexpr static int a = 34;
    int arr[a][2];
};
```

> But using static would just make it common for all objects, I want each object to have a different array size, that I want to take as input

You can use `std::vector` as shown below:

```
class equation
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;  
  public:
  //constructor that uses constructor initializer list to initialize arr  
  equation(std::size_t row, std::size_t col): arr(row, std::vector<int>(col))
  {
      
  }
};
int main()
{
    equation e(3,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But using static would just make it common for all objects, I want each object to have a different array size, that I want to take as input.

Comment: @PrakalpManavThakur Then you can use `std::vector`. See i have added an example of how to use `std::vector` at the end of my updated answer.

Comment: @PrakalpManavThakur `std::vector` is the simplest solution to your problem in C++. Any other solutions are more complicated or not legal in C++.