# Why are only some consts useable in compile time array sizes?

Tags: c++

I ran across this seemingly odd behavior. A `const` at top level can be used for array size declarations, but not when the `const` is in a class.

Here's [a compiler explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMa87aa71) for MSVC, CLANG and GCC all producing an error:

> expression did not evaluate to a constant

It's not really a constant if it's not `const` at the top level?

There's some argument to be made because top level constants can often be stored in read-only memory, while constants that are not at top level cannot. But is this behavior correct?

```
struct A {
    const int i{ 3 };
};

int main()
{
    const int ii{ 3 };
    A a;
    int j[a.i]{}; // C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
    int k[ii]{};
}
```

Comment: The fact that `A::i` is const does not mean it is known at compile time. You can use e.g. `A a{ 4 }` to set it to 4 (a ctor of `A` could also do something like that). BTW - this would still be the case if `A a` was const.

Comment: Do you want a practical explanation why this can't be made to work (see comment above) or do you want a language-lawyery explanation of how the standard specifies this?

Comment: @wohlstad Same error with `A a{ 4 }`

Comment: @user17732522 any explanation would do. Both a.i and ii are initialized.

Comment: @doug - this is exactly what I meant. When you use `A a{4}` A::i will be 4 (not 3). instead of 4 is can also be a variable. Bottom line - the value of A::i is cannot be known at compile time even though it is a const member (which means it cannot be changed AFTER the object containing it is constructed).

Comment: @doug `i` is a non-static data member and so would require an object to be used on. Thus it cannot be used in a context that requires a compile time constant. You can solve this by making `i` a `constexpr static` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72505848/12002570). That is `a.i` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/EsTsEPfxP) of being about to choose another value for `i` other than `3`.

Comment: Interesting. Same error with `const A a;` Apparently class members can't be compile time consts.

Comment: @doug making an `A` object `const` doesn't change the fact that separate `A` objects can be initialized with different `i` values. And that flexibility means the value of `i` can't be evaluated at compile-time. Period.

Comment: @doug No, they(class members) can be compile time constant if you use `constexpr static` i.e., make them a constexpr static data member. See in my answer below.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. There is only one `a.i`  Why would it matter if there was a b.i or c.i?

Comment: @AnoopRana Yes, a static constexpr works great. I usually use that like `constexpr int ii{3};` I just don't get why a regular const works in some places but not others.

Comment: @doug Because in the class nonstatic data member case, the `this` pointer is a runtime constructor(in your eg) and hence it cannot be used in a compile time context. This is mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: @doug why is this concept so hard to understand? The `a.i` member is simply not in a context where it can be evaluated at compile-time, only at runtime. It is stored in memory depending on where the object's `this` pointer is pointing at. Whereas the `ii` variable is in a context where it can be evaluated at compile-time, it doesn't even require memory storage in this case.

Comment: @doug Perhaps you're assuming that `const` implies compile time constant which is a **wrong assumption**. For example, in the following example `size` is not a constant expression. `int i = 10; const int size = i;`. The same example is added in my answer which has some more details about this.

Comment: If we and the optimizer can deduce a value of a variable from the program source and know that it is definitely a fixed number, it is not enough to use that variable as a compile-time constant.

Comment: _"Do you want a practical explanation why this can't be made to work (see comment above) or do you want a language-lawyery explanation of how the standard specifies this"_ - _we_ want the latter ;)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can use (meaning perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on) objects with lifetime starting outside a constant expression only if they are variables marked `constexpr` or their subobjects (plus some other special cases, that I don't think are important here, see [[expr.const]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4) for details).

That you can use a `const int` variable at all in a constant expression is already a very specific exception. Essentially `const`-qualified integral and enumeration type variables are also *usable in constant expressions* if you could have added `constexpr` to them (meaning that their initializer expression is a constant expression).

This exception is there I guess purely for historical reasons, since it had been allowed before `constexpr` was introduced in C++11.

Note that all of this talks about *variables* and their subobjects. Non-static data members are specifically not variables and the exception doesn't apply to them. With `constexpr` this is more obvious by not allowing it on the declaration of a non-static data member in the first place.

The historical rule was never extended to encompass other types that could be marked `constexpr`, so e.g. `const A a;` will not help although that would actually cause `a` to be storable in read-only memory the same way a `const int` would.

If an object is none of the cases mentioned above, then an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it in a constant expression is not allowed, since it is assumed that the value of the object is not determined at compile-time.

Now, in theory the compiler could still do some constant folding and determine that even other objects' values are definitively known at compile-time. But I think the intention is that whether or not an expression is a constant expression should be (reasonably) well-defined independently of the implementation and so shouldn't rely on how much analysis the compiler can do.

For example

```
A a;
A b(a);
```

is also guaranteed to result in `b.i == 3`. How far do you want to require a compiler to go back or keep track of evaluations? You would need to make some definitive specification if you want to keep the behavior consistent between compilers. But there is already a simple method to indicate that you want the compiler to keep track of the values. You just have to add `constexpr`:

```
constexpr A a;
constexpr A b(a);
```

Now `b.i` can be used as array index (whether or not it is `const` and whether or not it is initialized).

With the current rules, any compiler only needs to evaluate the value of objects at compile-time when it sees a `constexpr` variable or a `const` integral/enumeration type variable. For all other variables it doesn't need to keep track of values or backtrack when it sees them used in a context which requires a constant expression.
The additional effect of `constexpr` implying `const` on the variable makes sure that its value will also never be changed in a valid program and so the compiler doesn't need worry about updating or invalidating the value after the initial computation either. And whether or not an expression is a constant expression is (mostly) implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

`ii` is a compile-time constant. Its value is known at compile-time, and cannot be changed at runtime.  So, `ii` can be used for fixed array sizes at compile-time.

`A::i` is not a compile-time constant.  It is a non-static instance member.  Its value is not known until runtime. After an `A` object is constructed and its `i` member is initialized, the value of `i` cannot be changed because of the `const`, but the caller can initialize `i` with whatever value it wants, eg: `A a{123};`, and thus different `A` objects can have different `i` values. So, `i` cannot be used for fixed array sizes at compile-time.  But, it can be used for dynamic array sizes at runtime, via `new[]`, `std::vector`, etc.

Comment: Sure different A objects could be initialized differently but there is only one there just like there is only one ii and both were initialized.

Comment: @doug, I think this is a design choice on the language. You don't want the compiler going down a black-hole of analysis to consider all possible constructor logic. In this case its easy, yes, but where to draw the line? It's simpler to prompt the user to write `static constexpr`

Comment: @doug "*different A objects could be initialized differently but there is only one there*" - Every instance of `A` has its own copy of `i`. At the point where the `j[]` array is declared, the compiler doesn't know yet whether there is only 1 `A` object. Not that it matters. If you want only 1 `i` regardless of how many `A`s are used, make `A::i` be `static` instead. A `static const` member that is initialized inline is a compile-time constant.

Comment: @doug "A objects could be initialized differently" - thats they key here. Because there is a **possibility** that it could be initialized differently makes it a non-constant expression

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

Your assumption that `const` always implies compile time constant is incorrect. See examples at the end of this answer for more details on this.

---

Now the **problem** in using `a.i` as the size of an array is that in standard C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**, but since `i` is a non-static data member, it requires an object to be used on. In other words, after construction of the class object nonstatic data member `i` gets initialized, which in turn means that `a.i` is not a *constant expression*, hence we get the mentioned error saying:

> expression did not evaluate to a constant

To **solve** this, you can make `i` be a `constexpr static` data member, as shown below. This works because using a static data member doesn't require an object instance (and hence no `this` pointer).

```
struct A {
    constexpr static int i{ 3 };
};

int main()
{
    const int ii{ 3 };
    A a;
    int j[a.i]{}; //Correct now and works in all compilers
    int k[ii]{};
}
```

---

> I just don't get why a regular const works in some places but not others.

Perhaps you assuming that `const` implies compile time constant which is a **wrong assumption**. An example might help you understand this better:

```
int i = 10;         //i is not a constant expression
const int size = i; //size is not a constant expression as the initializer is not a constant expression

//------vvvv------>error here as expected since size is not a constant expression
int arr[size]{};
```

On the other hand if you were to make `i` `const` as shown below, the program will work fine.

```
const int i = 10; //note the const added here so that now i is a constant expression
const int size = i; //size is a constant expression as the initializer is a constant expression

//------vvvv------>NO ERROR HERE as expected since size is a constant expression
int arr[size]{};
```